# incomplete vector space of continously differentiable functions

Tags: analysis, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

Consider the vector space

$C^1[a, b] := \{f: [a, b] \to \mathbb{C} \space |\space  f$ continuously differentiable$\}$.

I now want to show that ($C^1[-1, 1]$, $||.||_\infty)$ is *not* complete (using the definition that a metric space $X$ is complete $<=>$ every Cauchy-series in X converges in X).

Well, using this definition, I thought it would disprove the statement if I could come up with a series of functions $f_n(x)$ that is continuously differentiable for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, but converges to a function $f$ that's not continuously differentiable. But I haven't found such a series of functions yet. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What metric are you using on this space?

Comment: @moran: Do you have a favorite sequence of smooth functions that converges uniformly to a non-differentiable function?

Answer (score 0):

There exists a sequence of $C^([-1,1])$ functions that uniformly converges to the absolute value of $x$ on $I=[-1,1]$. You may take:

$$ f_N(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{N}\binom{1/2}{n}(x^2-1)^n,$$
that is the truncated Taylor series of $\sqrt{1-z}$ evaluated in $z=1-x^2$. This sequence, for instance, plays a major role in the Lebesgue's proof of Weierstrass approximation theorem.